# Imprimir direto sem passar pela caixa de dialogo do php

Tags: php, javascript, html, navegador-de-internet, impressão

Eu uso o java script para imprimir somente o conteúdo de uma div,mais eu preciso que não use a caixa de dialogo de impressão do navegador.

Motivo: Eu criei uma formatação para o texto,quando vai para imprimir pela a caixa de dialogo esta perdendo minha formatação.

Como poderia acertar isso ?

Segue abaixo meus códigos:

> DIV:

```
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    width:100px;

  }
  #div1{
    border:solid 1px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 5px black;
    font-size: 8px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial;
  }
  </style>
```

> JS:

```
<script>
function cont(){
   var conteudo = document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;
   tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');
   tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
   tela_impressao.window.print();
   tela_impressao.window.close();
}
</script>
```

> CONTEUDO:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
<div id="div1" style="width:400px; margin:0 auto;"> 
<?php
echo"<div id='print' class='conteudo'>";
      echo"<center><img src='logo.png' width='200';margin:0 auto;></center>";
      echo"<center><b>COMPROVANTE DE TROCA DE VASILHAME</center></b>";
      echo"<hr>";
      echo "<p>COMPROVANTE N°: $v_cupom   </p>";
      echo "<p>LOJA: $v_loja_num - $v_loja_desc </p>";
      echo "<p>VASILHAME: $v_cod_ean - $v_vasilhame </p>";
      echo "QUANTIDADE: $v_quantidade";
      echo"<hr>";
      echo"<center>DATA: $v_data HORA: $v_hora  </center>";
 echo "</div>";
?>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<center><a href="index.php" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="cont();" value="Imprimir">IMPRIMIR</a></center>
<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Como você abre uma nova janela, o style não está atribuído a ela. Tente colocar o style dentro do conteúdo.

Comment: @LF Ziron Mais o style já esta dentro do conteúdo.

Comment: Não está não, a variável conteudo tem apenas o innerHTML da div #print.

Comment: A entendi,mais tem como passar ali no Java script o head ?

Comment: Sim, aplique um id a sua tag style, digamos que use myStyle e utilize no script: conteudo = document.getElementById("myStyle").outerHTML; conteudo += document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;

Comment: Perfeito,deu certo,Obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Boa noite, Otácio.

Primeiramente, não é possível imprimir direto sem aparecer a caixa de diálogo, imagine só quantos sites sairiam imprimindo coisas em sua impressora sem sua permissão! Seria uma bagunça!

Segundamente, o problema da impressão é porque ele está abrindo uma nova janela com o conteúdo, porém a folha de estilo não está indo junto. Faça essa modificação no seu código javascript e teste novamente:

```
<script>
function cont(){
    window.print();
}
</script>
```

Abraço.

Comment: colocando somente dessa forma ai não esta imprimindo.

Comment: Acertado,Obrigado pela ajuda também. Abraço.

Answer (score 0):

Solução:
 Assim com indicado por nosso colega @LF Ziron inserir o css junto com a função de imprimir.
 Segue código:

```
<script>
    function cont(){
       var conteudo = conteudo = document.getElementById("div1").outerHTML; 
                                 document.getElementById('print').innerHTML;
       tela_impressao = window.open('about:blank');
       tela_impressao.document.write(conteudo);
       tela_impressao.window.print();
       tela_impressao.window.close();

    }
</script>
```